# Ограничение по дате

Tags: sql-server

Пытаюсь сделать ограничения по дате внутри case.

```
select
count(case when dpd>1 then id end) as a
AVG(cash_to_client) as b
```

a - должна браться как date_time плюс один месяц

b - просто date_time

Понимаю что нужно использовать DATEADD(MONTH,1,date_time), но как его поместить в case или использовать через select без дальнейшего участя в группировке не понимаю. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может объясните задачу чуть поподробнее.

Comment: a-расчитывает кол-во клиентов с просрочкой спустя 1 месяц или же в момент date_time + 1 месяц.
b-сумма кредита, которая высчитывается сразу или же в момент date_time .

Пытаюсь понять как для a задать фильтр dateadd(month,1,date_time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну тогда примерно так

```
select
   count(case when getdate() > DATEADD(MONTH,1,date_time) then id end) as a
   AVG(cash_to_client) as b
```

Если у Вас есть дата погашения кредита, то используйте её вместо `getdate()`

`AVG(cash_to_client)` - это средняя сумма кредита в целом.

Если нужно по просроченным то

**среднее** - `AVG(case when getdate() > DATEADD(MONTH,1,date_time) then cash_to_client end)`

**совокупный** - `SUM(case when getdate() > DATEADD(MONTH,1,date_time) then cash_to_client end)`